# DexException when using Firebase Messaging in a library

Tags: android, firebase

I'm using `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1` in a library which provides some additional functionality on top of FGM. When I add the library to an application (either as a locally installed Maven dependency or as a module dependency) and apply the `com.google.gms.google-services` plugin at the bottom of the script I get the following error when trying to build the app:

```
example-notifications:transformClassesWithDexForDebug

Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zza;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/zza;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:591)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:546)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:528)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:164)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:188)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:504)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:example-notifications:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
```

The app's build script is as follows:

```
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile 'library-using-fgm'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And finally the library's just to show the declared dependency:

```
android {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the build output I noticed

```
google-services plugin could not detect any version for
com.google.android.gms or com.google.firebase, default version: 9.0.0
will be used.
please apply google-services plugin at the bottom of the
build file.
```

being printed out. Despite having the Google Play Services gradle plugin at the bottom of the app's script, it seems like it's not able to pick out the version of FGM which is being used based on the transitive dependencies and thus applies the wrong tasks to the build which result in this error.

I have managed to workaround this by changing the app's dependencies to

```
dependencies {
    compile 'library-using-fgm'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
}
```

however is there a better solution to this issue which doesn't result in re-declaring the FGM dependency outside of the library?